# Lex V1 group message

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

**I am working on chat bot in Amazon lex v1 ,In that I want to display two messages when the client invoke the bot. But I am facing issue .with lambda**

```
        var messageToUse = {
        contentType : "Composite",
        content :{"messages":[{"type":"PlainText","group":1,"value":"welcome"},{"type":"PlainText","group":2,"value":"To GAC"}]}
        };
  const response = {
        "dialogAction": 
        {"type": "Close",
        "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
        "message": messageToUse
            
    }
```

};
callback(response);

[**Expected Result should be this**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqdKZ.png)

Answer (score 2):

Lex V1 is limited when it comes to working with the API for message groups. The tutorial you were following was able to get multiple messages by using message groups in the content designer (Lex's designer UI). This is different than returning multiple messages through a Lambda function.

Adding the responses in the content designer

[image]

A preview of how the responses will look

[image]

Unfortunately, the JSON for messages was not a list/array in Lex V1. [It only supported key value pairs](https://repost.aws/questions/QU4MCxtfkMRVygfX8PyH01wg/aws-connect-aws-lex-send-multiple-messages). This means that a Lex V1 Bot only expects a single message from the Lambda and you cannot return more than one at a time.

The only way you can make Lex V1 appear like it is returning multiple messages is to use a custom front end. If you plan on using a custom front end, you can parse the `message.content` JSON into different message bubbles yourself.

If you would like to be able to set message groups through a lambda function, I recommend you try using Lex V2. The JSON for messages in Lex V2 expects a list, meaning that you can return multiple messages at once and they will appear in separate bubbles in the Lex V2 test console.

Here is an example of how to do this in Lex V2:

```
 return {
    "sessionState": {
        "dialogAction": {
            "type": "Close"
        },
        "intent": {
            "confirmationState": "None",
            "name": "TestIntent",
            "state": "Fulfilled"
        }
    },
    "messages": [ 
        { "contentType": "PlainText", "content": "Hi" }, 
        { "contentType": "PlainText", "content": "How are you?" }, 
        { "contentType": "PlainText", "content": "How may I help?" } 
    ]};
```

And also how they appear in the test console.

[image]

I'm sorry this isn't the answer you were hoping for but I hope it helps anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply **Kera**.I am totally blank please correct me does Lex v1 support Group message are not. If it supports means kindly help me with your sample code if doesn't tell me another solution. I have catch here I should not go for Lex v2 because I am integrating my Lex bot with Genesy Inbound Message .It only support Lex v1.

Comment: @SUBASHE From my own tests and research, it seems like you [cannot return message groups to a V1 Lex using a Lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52740107/send-group-multiple-messages-from-lambda-to-lex). I am not familiar with Genesys but it looks like they might [support V2](https://help.mypurecloud.com/articles/amazon-lex-v2-quick-start-guide/). Is there a specific reason you need to split the Lex messages to use this service? Such as a character limit or something similar?

Comment: once again thanks for you valid time .Genesys supports lex V2 for voice application but here I am doing chat application in that case it doesn't support lex V2.One again thanks for your help.

Comment: @SUBASHE if it helps remember to mark it as best answer. Good luck!