# Amazon Lex v1 group message

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

I am totally blank please correct me does `Lex v1` support `group messages`?

If it supports please kindly help me with examples.

I am unable to use `Lex v2` because I am integrating my `Lex` bot with `Genesys Inbound Message`. It only support `Lex v1`.

```
var messageToUse = 
{
    contentType : "Composite",
    content :
    {
        "messages":
        [
            {"type":"PlainText","group":1,"value":"welcome"},        
            {"type":"PlainText","group":2,"value":"To GAC"}
        ]
    }
};

const response = 
{
    "dialogAction": 
    {
        "type": "Close",
        "fulfillmentState": "Fulfilled",
        "message": messageToUse
    }
};
callback(response);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lex V1 does not support multiple response messages. This feature is supported in Lex V2 though.

Take a look at this answer for some suggestions on how you can achieve multiple response messages on Lex V1.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72623192/8880593