# AWS Lex V1 send a message bubble the first time an intent is triggered

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I currently have a Lex V1 bot with two intents. I want the bot to send a message before the first slot prompt is sent. I thought this could be done either by sending a message the first time the intent is triggered, or sending multiple prompts (if that is even possible).

For instance the user would say something like:

I want to change major

and the bot would respond with 2 messages:

- Warning: Changing this could impact you, advising is recommend
- Would you like to schedule advising?

I essentially just want to split this into two distinct message bubbles.
I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52493642/how-to-add-multiple-responses-in-aws-lex) for sending multiple response messages, but how do I send multiple prompt ones in a Lex V1 bot?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a lambda code hook for initialization and validation you can send multiple messages as a list which will display as seperate messages. You want to set the type to ElicitSlot. The response syntax in Lex V2 from the lambda would look like this:

```
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        return {'sessionState': {
            'dialogAction': {
                'type': 'ElicitSlot',
                'slotToElicit': 'NAME_OF_YOUR_SLOT'},
        },
            'intent': event['sessionState']['intent'],
            'messages': [{'contentType': 'PlainText',
                          'content': 'PUT FIRST MESSAGE HERE'},
                         {'contentType': 'PlainText',
                          'content': 'PUT SECOND MESSAGE HERE'}],
        }
```

It will be slightly different in Lex V1

Comment: I've since learned that Lex V1 does not support sending multiple message through a Lambda function since Lex V1 messages are structured as key value pairs and not lists. I ended up parsing the message into 2 bubbles in my custom front end. Thank you for your response though, it was helpful when I moved over to Lex V2.